# React youtube player - setting controls and showinfo to 0 doesn't remove youtube's controls or title

Tags: reactjs, youtube

I am using [react-youtube package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-youtube) and I have set the options to remove most of the youtube's branding and controls:

```
const options = {
  height: 'auto',
  width: '100%',
  playerVars: {
    // https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters
    controls: 0,
    enablejsapi: 1,
    modestbranding: 1,
    showinfo: 0
  }
} as const

<YouTube videoId="xyQ5qD-u-J7" opts={options} ref={videoElement}/>
```

But, the youtube frame is still showing all the options just as if it were displayed on the youtube channel. Why is the branding not removed?